# How to refactor IF statements into ternary operators in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hello I am trying to refactor my function but it doesn't seem to be working properly. It works fine normally which is the commented code. Am I writing this wrong or is there a fundamental flaw in my code?

```
function isPrime(num) {
  
  // if (num <= 1){
  //   return false
  // } else {
  //   for(var i = 2; i < num; i++){
  //   if(num % i === 0) return false;
  //   }
  // }
  
  num <= 1 ? false : {
    for(let i = 2; i < num; i++){
    num % 1 === 0 ? false 
  }}
  
  
  return true;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: In this case you shouldn't "refactor" it into an if statement.

Comment: You have to have at least one colon `:` and the other result `num % 1 === 0 ? false : true`

Comment: I would suggest you don't use nested ternaries for this. While they may save some lines of code, what you gain in brevity you more than lost in clarity.

Comment: But hey, if you really want to, here's a one-liner (*with a ternary*): `const isPrime = (n) => e > 1 && [...Array(Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n))).keys()].slice(2).every((d) => n % d);`

Comment: Oh so this is the most efficient way of writing the code? I am trying to refactor it into a ternary operator

Comment: That solution doesn't seem to work

Comment: Whoops, there's a typo. The first condition should be `n > 1` not `e > 1`. [Then it works.](https://tsplay.dev/wOAJpm)

Comment: I'd focus on improving the algorithm rather than syntax, if I were you. For example, if you already know that `num` is odd, is it really necessary to check 4, 6, 8 etc?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, no language having the ternary operator allows running a block of statements, which is what you are doing.  The ternary operator is a shorthand version of:

```js
let result;
if (<condition>)
    result = resultTrue;
else
    result = resultFalse;
```

Unless JavaScript stabs be in the back on this one, `for` is a statement that doesn't return anything, and therefore cannot be used the way you want.

The best you could do, I guess, would be:

```js
function isPrime(num) {
    if (num <= 1) {
        return false;
   }
   for(var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
       if(num % i === 0) return false;
   }
}
```

The `else` part omitted since hitting the line after the `if` necessarily means that the condition for it was not met.

Answer (score 0):

Technically what you have can be brought to life with an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
function isPrime(num) {
  return num <= 1 ? false :
    (n => {
      for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i === 0) return false;
      }
      return true;
    })(num)
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(i, isPrime(i));
}
```

Now it works and there is a ternary operator inside.

---

Even the attempt without `return` can be done, just you need `isPrime` made into an arrow function:

```js
let isPrime = num => num <= 1 ? false :
  (n => {
    for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
      if (n % i === 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
  })(num);

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(i, isPrime(i));
}
```

Tadaam, the `num <= 1 ? false :` part is literally there in the first line, without that nasty `return`.
[image]

But realistically this is not how `isPrime` should be implemented, your very first attempt is the best one so far.

---

If you want an actual improvement, use the fact that divisors come in pairs. If `x` is a divisor of `num`, then `num/x` is also divisor of `num`. So if you were looking for all divisors of `num`, you would find them in pairs as soon as `x=num/x=sqrt(num)`, so it's enough to check numbers between `2` and `Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num))`, inclusive. As you preferably don't want JS to calculate this number in every iteration (when checking the condition), you could count downwards, so

```
for (let i = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num)); i >= 2; i--)
```